# Reboot when no network connection does not work!

Tags: bash, networking, cron, raspberry-pi, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi that I use as a NAS for my local network. It works fine, but when I turn off the router to which the pi is connected, it permanently loses the connection. To be able to connect to the network again it has to be restarted. Therefore I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! ping -q -w 1 -c 1 $(ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
then
        service networking restart

        sleep 60

        if ! ping -q -w 1 -c 1 $(ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
        then
                reboot
        fi
fi
```

It basically tries to ping the router. If it fails it restarts the networking service (for when a simple error occurred and a reboot is not necessary). If it then still can't ping to the router it reboots. I set this up as a cronjob every 10 minutes, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I put this line in the crontab:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /root/rebooter.sh >> rebooter.log 2>&1
```

Whit no connection this is the output:

```
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface]
            [-M pmtudisc-hint] [-m mark] [-S sndbuf]
            [-T tstamp-options] [-Q tos] [hop1 ...] destination
/root/rebooter.sh: Line 5: service: Command not found.
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface]
            [-M pmtudisc-hint] [-m mark] [-S sndbuf]
            [-T tstamp-options] [-Q tos] [hop1 ...] destination
/root/rebooter.sh: Line 11: reboot: Command not found.
```

With connection this is the output:

```
PING 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.178.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.985/0.985/0.985/0.000 ms
```

Comment: can you try to add `@reboot </abs/path/to script> &` to your crontab? and reboot?

Comment: Any error messages in `rebooter.log` ?

Comment: @Simply_Me What does that do?

Comment: @BrainStone this to let cron know to run this script at reboot with `&` for not to wait for script complete.

Comment: @Simply_Me This is not quite what I want or need.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am currently checking!

Comment: @BrainStone does the process start? If so, what do the log say?

Comment: @Simply_Me check the edit.

Comment: So it's not finding `ip`, `reboot`, or `service`. Looks like you need to set PATH in the shell script, since cron does not read any shell dot files that will set PATH. Edit that shell script so `export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` is the 2nd line.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That is the solution! It now reboots when the router is not connected! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your `if` statement.

`if ! ping -q -w 1 -c 1 $(ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)`

More specifically:

`ping -q -w 1 -c 1 $(ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)`

The host `ip` isn't passed properly.

Note that each portion works by itself (i.e. `ping host` and `ip r....`).

This has been working for me:

```
$ ip r | grep "default" | cut -d ' ' -3 | xargs ping -q -w 1 -c 1
```

Try to incorporate it with your `if` statements.
`xargs` takes the output from previous pipes and use it for `ping`, whereas previously the ip wasn't passed to the `ping` half of the code. Try it in command line :-)

Changed to `netstat` rather then `ip r` which also works with Pi yet is general enough to be used across other Linux dists.

The script below:

It properly gets the host name to ping and enters the statement(s) in case of a `0` (input, i.e. when the device is disconnected).

Also re structured the `if` statement with `[]` brackets, and assigned a variable for cleaner statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

test_host=`netstat -nr | grep "UG" | awk '{ print $2}' | xargs ping -q -w 1 -c 1 | grep "received" | awk '{ print $4 }'`
if [ "$test_host" == "0" ] || [ -z "$test_host" ] ;
then
    echo "service networking restart"

    sleep 60
    test_host=`netstat -nr | grep "UG" | awk '{ print $2}' | xargs ping -q -w 1 -c 1 | grep "received" | awk '{ print $4 }'`
    if [ "$test_host" == "0" ] || [ -z "$test_host" ] ;
    then
            echo "reboot"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't think this won't make any difference since when the Pi is not connected the `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` command has an empty output.

Comment: @BrainStone but earlier it would have always been passed as empty (i.e. always in "not connected state").

Comment: @BrainStone check updated answer, this script should work for you.

Comment: why did you put the commands in an echo?

Comment: @BrainStone because it was about fixing the statements, and not about `reboot` .... didn't feel like rebooting my system :-).

Comment: Don't forget the `export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. But other than that it is working like this!

Comment: @BrainStone great! not sure, it ran on my system without the `export`, I guess we have diff settings. Please note, I've modified the `if`s; this is final though.

Comment: It works for me aswell as it has been before

Comment: @BrainStone earlier I forgot to add the `ping` component. Now it prints `1` or `0` from `1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms` output from second `grep`. Specifically, the `1` or `0` from `1 received` using `awk`.

Comment: Like this I get this error `Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface]
            [-M pmtudisc-hint] [-m mark] [-S sndbuf]
            [-T tstamp-options] [-Q tos] [hop1 ...] destination`

Comment: @BrainStone that's odd, it works here. What's the output of this `netstat -nr | grep "UG" | awk '{ print $2}' | xargs ping -q -w 1 -c 1 | grep "received" | awk '{ print $4 }'` in command line? You should get either `1` (connected) or `0` (not connected).

Comment: 1, 0 or this error. It happens when `netstat -nr | grep "UG" | awk '{ print $2}'` returns nothing.

Comment: @BrainStone I edited the script to account for empty string (i.e. nothing). This now accounts for 1,0,and empty string cases.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem. The problem is not `test_host` being empty but `netstat -nr | grep "UG" | awk '{ print $2}'` being empty and therefore not passing an ip to `ping`. This is causing the problems.